# What do array[] and array[i] operators do in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to teach myself coding, and I stumbled on an example I don't understand. Could someone give me an overview of what this code is supposed to do? I'm a bit confused about int a[] and what is later int a[i]. I know what an array is, but could someone please explain how this is being used in this context? Thank you in advance.

```
public class all {

    public int select(int a[],int n,int x)
        {
            int i=0;
            while(i<n && a[i]<x)
            {
                if(a[i]<0)
                    a[i]=-a[i];
                i++;
            }
            return(a[i-1]);
        }

}
```

Comment: Possibly you need to revise arrays once more. Pick up paper & pen and try what is happening. That way you will learn solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
        if(a[i]<0) 
            a[i]=-a[i];
        i++;
```

is he same like this

```
        if(a[i]<0) { 
            a[i]=-a[i];
}
        i++;
```

`a[i]` -> value at the position i, into the Array

`if(a[i]<0) {` -> if the value at position i is smaller than 0, also negative number

`a[i]=-a[i];` -> replace the value with a reverse sign.

`i++` -> increment loop Counter

Also what is done here: negative numbers convert to positive numbers.

`while(i<n && a[i]<x) ->` i = loop counter; if i smaller n and the value at position i in the array is smaller than x, then go into the loop.

`return(a[i-1]);` -> return the last value, that has been checked into the while loop

Answer (score 0):

the method gets an array and two int args `n` and `x` (as a side note, I must say the names leave a lot to be desired...) 
anyway, lets see what are the args for. they both are used in the while loop. the condition `i<n` tells us that `n` serves as upper limit to the iteration, while the condition `a[i]<x` tells us that `x` is used as upper limit to the values in the array.

so far, we can say:
`select` method receives an array, int arg specifying iteration-upper-limit and int arg specifying cell-value-upper-limit.
iterate over the array until you reach position specified by iteration-upper-limit or you reach a cell value that exceeds cell-value-upper-limit (which ever comes first)

can you continue to say what's being done inside the loop? it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Hi there. Would you consider adding your contributions using a capital letter at the beginning of sentences, please? It is quite standard for written English, and makes things much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

1.) a[] is the declaration of array.size is not defined.

2.)In a[i], i is the index number of the array...that means indicating the position of the element in array.

Answer (score -1):

`a[]` is an array and we do not know its length. `n` must be lower than the length of `a[]` or it will throw an exception. It  it traverses from the first element toward the last untill it one element is larger than `x`. it returns these element's absolute value which were traversed

Comment: what about the inside of the loop ??

Comment: `n` must be **lower** then the array size!